# Span Rendering Bug in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm having an issue with Chrome on macOS where adding `span` tags to text in a `div` affects the spacing between words and sometimes where the line breaks.

It is my assumption that unstyled `span` tags shouldn't change text rendering and that two identical `div`s with the same content and styling except for adding spans should render identically. This doesn't appear to be the case and can be seen in the image below. Two `div`s are overlaid to show the rendering discrepancy, where the `div` with the red text in front has `span`s in blue and the `div` with the black text behind does not.

[image: Rendering mismatch after adding spans]

This may seem very minor but in some cases this difference is affecting where the line is breaking (although very rare and hard to reproduce). This can be seen in the next image.

[image: Rendering mismatch affects line breaking]

I've setup a JSBin to demonstrate the difference when adding span tags. Adjust the width of the HTML output panel slowly and you should see discrepancies in the rendering of the two `div`s. Move the width to 658px to see the line breaking issue.

https://jsbin.com/qajekub/edit?html,css,output

So my question is, why is there an alignment discrepancy between two identical `div`s but one has `span`s? Is there something I'm missing? A CSS property or default styling that would be causing this?

This happens in Chrome 55 on macOS. It's not occurring in Firefox or Safari as far as I can tell and I'm unable to test on other operating systems.

Comment: So are you asking why at some places the text looks like having a shadow?

Comment: Essentially. Why is there an alignment discrepancy between two identical `div`s but one has `span`s? I overlaid two `div`s with different colours to highlight the difference in rendering.

Comment: You either have a very very good vision, or I'm starting to get blind, because for me, everything is the same size

Comment: There's definitely a difference there... honest... maybe I'll update my image with a larger one...

Comment: Well yes it's there, even if both `<div>s` have the same font color. I would say it's mainly because of the `text-align: justify;` and then some rendering issue

Comment: Even removing `justify` there's still issues. Having `justify` on there just helps make it more obvious. I've added another image showing the line breaking issue this is causing even with `justify` turned off.

Comment: No problems on Win, if that means something :). Well... macOS...always 'interesting' html/css rendering... :)